# Notebook built-in keyboard sporadically not working after boot

Tags: boot, drivers, keyboard, laptop

problem is as follows:

Sporadically, when I boot Ubuntu (22.04.3), the keyboard doesn't work. Neither at login manager nor at desktop after login. No key responds.

I can boot up to 3 to 5 times, sometimes more, and the keyboard doesn't work. Then I maybe boot 2 times where it does work. It seems to be random.

A few things are to note: Before loading Ubuntu, at the GRUB menu, the keyboard *always* works. Arrow keys / enter key and letters (grub console) all respond. The keyboard does also work in UEFI settings. So the problem only occurs after loading the OS.

I noticed, that during the boot messages some "key sequence" appears: **^\^\^\^\^\** (one after one shortly). Could that be related?

The problem started to occur maybe 3-4 months ago, possibly after some update, but I don't remember for sure.

I already tried some linux live image of Ubuntu 23.10 with a newer kernel. The same problem. Could boot a few times with working keyboard, then without. Also the **^\^\^\** ... appeared.

A USB keyboard (plugged in before or after the problem occurs) is working, but it's not very handy at times.

I specifically needed to know, if this is a hardware issue (although it works in GRUB / UEFI) or if it could be solved without replacing the notebook (drivers?).

I'm using a Fujitsu notebook ("Lifebook"). Of course I can provide additional information or some log output if required.

--- caldon724